# How to inverse matrix equations?

Tags: code-request

I've never used matematica before so still learning. I'm trying to show that two equations below are equal to one another. To do that, doing an inverse transformation from 3.5-3 to 3.5-4 would accomplish that.

The equation in Matrix Form:

[image]

Any help on how to get started in mathematica would be appreciated.

Comment: Check documentation for `Inverse`.

Answer (score 6):

```
A = {{Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 0, Cos[\[Phi]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]],  0, -Sin[\[Phi]]}, {Cos[\[Theta]], 1, 0}};
A//MatrixForm
FullSimplify[Inverse[A]]//MatrixForm
```

[image]